# Which is best method to read or write a particular line in file in perl?

Tags: perl, file

I am trying to read a last line of the file.
And There are many method available to read particular line of file.

first:

```
  @array=<FILE_HANDLE>;
    $line=(reverse @array)[0];
```

second: ReadBackwards package

```
$bw = File::ReadBackwards->new( 'log_file' ) or
                        die "can't read 'log_file' $!" ;
 $log_line = $bw->readline;
```

I want to know that In perl which is preferable method, whether using package 
or stored whole file content into the variable .

Comment: How do you define _best_? Fastest, most memory-efficient, easiest to read for the next guy?

Answer (score 4):

Your title asks a different question than your body.

To read the last (or nth from last) line from an arbitrarily large file, absolutely do use File::ReadBackwards.

To read or write an arbitrary single line in a file, use Tie::File:

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @line, 'Tie::File', 'filename' or die "unable to open filename: $!";
print "line 123 is $line[123].";
$line[42] = 'abc';
print "line 42 is now abc.";
```

For large files, this will be significantly more expensive than File::ReadBackwards, because it will need to read through the entire file up to the line you want to modify (or through the entire file, if using a negative index, so if you are doing that, you are better off using File::ReadBackwards and then manually updating the file).

Comment: For comparison, [this](http://pastebin.com/2Tqv4qym) is an efficient alternative to your Tie::File snippet. It is uses *far* less memory and is *much* faster.

Comment: @ikegami: do you have numbers for the "less memory"?

Comment: Ignoring the line cache (which has a configurable size), T::F keeps in memory the index of each line it encounters. In your example, that would be every line of the file. IIRC, it was something like 64 bytes per line on the machine I was using. For your typical Perl program file, reading the file using T::F actually uses more memory than storing the entire file in one scalar in memory!!

Comment: @ikegami: that should be an asnwer!

Comment: @Fabio Turati, You mean the linked code? it's specifically for small negative offsets. ysth's Tie::File snippet was using `$line[-10]` instead of `$line[42]` at the time. It's not a complete answer by far.

Comment: @ikegami To be honest I'm behind a firewall that blocks access to pastebin, so I haven't seen it. But your description sounded promising, and the explanation that T::F takes more memory than storing the entire file is certainly interesting. That's why I was asking you to promote your comment(s) to an answer. But... Your call. If you think it is not enough for an answer, fine.

Comment: @ikegami do you want to add your paste bin code to my answer, or make your own answer with it and whatever you want to take from mine and I'll delete my answer?

Comment: @ysth, Incorporate it into your answer if you wish.  I don't have an answer in me given the lack of clarity of the question.

Comment: @Fabio Turati, You can see it [here](http://www.adaelis.com/misc/temp/replace_tenth_last_line.txt) or [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120269/tiefile)

Answer (score -2):

The thing is - there isn't a way that doesn't rely on reading the whole file. Files start at the beginning, and your process *will* have to seek all the way through. 
This is the most expensive task your code will be doing, so it makes very little difference which approach you take.

So I'd go for a very simple:

```
 my $last_line; 
 while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ) { $last_line = $line }; 
 print $last_line,"\n";
```

This may look inefficient, but it's doing no more than the other things are - reading the whole file, and discarding everything but the final line.

If - as your question suggests - you're after a -specific- line - you can either use testing `$.` (current line number) or a regular expression and 'bail out' of the loop when a condition is met. Thus you don't read the whole file, which is marginally more efficient.

E.g.:

```
while ( my $line = <$filehandle> ) { 
    $last_line = $line;
    last if $. >= 100; #bails out after we hit line 100. 
    last if m/END FILE/; #looks for 'END FILE' on the line, and bails out. 
}; 
print $last_line,"\n";
```

Comment: You can read a file in blocks from the end, searching for a newline. That way you don't read the whole file.

Comment: @rustyx yes that is what File::ReadBackwards does for you